# Как по клику по ячейке вызвать форму для ввода данных?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Требуется в таблицах реализовать схему, чтобы по клику на ячейку открывалась форма для ввода данных и в нее (форму) также передавались параметры из ячейки, по которой кликают и соседних ячеек.
Форма может быть любая в т.ч. ввиде отдельного листа.
Возможные варианты:

1. Событие onClick по ячейкам нет в таблицах.
2. Кнопки-картинки - не жестко зафиксированы и могут двигаться  -> высока вероятность ошибки (для каждой строки списка придется назначать много кнопок)
3. Картинка привязанная к ячейке, не привязывается к скрипту.
4. Ссылка в ячейке на скрипт опубликованный как web app -> две проблемы: совершается переход на другую страницу (как бы его заблокировать?) и не вызывается функция (как бы ее вызвать?)

   ```
   function doGet(e) {
     Test(e.parameter.a1)   
   }

   function Test(A){
       Browser.msgBox(A + 'Tect')
   }
   ```
5. Может быть какой-то add-on к браузеру?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю? Какие могут быть еще варианты для вызова формы? Очень не хочется это делать по событию onEdit - неюзерфрендли.

Вызов формы нужен мне для двух целей:

1. Вызывать форму из списка транзакции, чтобы вносить и редактировать
   данные. Здесь можно будет применить - onEdit
2. Вызывать форму, чтобы сделать поиск по выпадающему списку - здесь только onClick, видимо.

Comment: Если вопрос заключается в заголовке, то вы на него отвечаете первым же пунктом. Возможно, вам стоит определиться с пользовательским поведением, а потом уже разрабатывать интерфейс. Вопрос слишком общий, на него нельзя дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: С пользовательским поведением я определился - мне нужно найти решение как запускать скрипт именно по клику.  Если со своей целью №1  я определился - сделаю по onEdit чекбокса, то с целью №2 пока не определился. Мне нужен поиск по выпадающему списку, в стандарте поиска нет, но можно его сделать с использованием скрипта, вопрос только как вызывать это скрипт? Эта вроде бы "мелкая" проблема остановила весь проект и и заставляет уйти в html, php и JS, а этого не хотелось бы делать.

Comment: > Очень не хочется это делать по событию onEdit - неюзерфрендли.

Comment: Показывая диалоги из простых триггеров, вы можете нарваться на непреодолимые ограничения. Вы же сами написали, что > Событие onClick по ячейкам нет в таблицах. Поиска никакого не будет. Проверяйте в триггере, какое значение получили в списке и реагируйте.

Comment: Спасибо!  Другими совами вы мне говорите, что никакого решения сделать поиск по списку ни в гугул формс ни в шитс нет?  Т.е. моя надежда сделать красивую форму ввода инструментами гугла обречена на провал.... Придется делать одним из спсобов: 1. весь список выводить снизу на листе, ставить сверху автофильтр и им искать, а значение в форму на листе будет передаваться по изменению автофильтра (останется решить вопрос, в какое из множества мест она будет попадать)  2. на внешнем url повесить JS форму, переходить на нее по ссылке из шитс, передавать туда гет параметры, и назад результаты по АПИ.

Comment: Уже больше похоже на правду. Хотелось бы, конечно увидеть пример, но теперь более ясно понятно, то Таблицы пока такое не поддерживают.

Comment: Я пока писал вам нашел приемлемое решение (медлеенное правда, но в целом рабочее), 99% что сработает,но нужно проверить: по изменению чекбокса переходим на отдельный лист где находится справочник и авто фильтр, авто фильтре ищем, по изменению нас возвращает на предыдущий лист и передается найденное значение. PS "Пример" уже очень большой и слишком залинкован на внешние ресурсы, чтобы его можно было выложить

Comment: Интересно, а происходит ли какое-нибудь событие при переходе по гиперссылке на соседний лист?

Comment: onOpen. У вас есть телеграм ? Чат по Таблицам и скриптам https://t.me/googleappsscriptrc